# How can I change a targeted string in a list of strings?

Tags: python

This is where my fill-in-the-blanks game begin. I need help replacing the old sentence with a new sentence when the user answer correctly. I'm still not sure if everything should be done in one function or get a different one. My main function is "def answer_check(answer, sentence, blank_space):". I want to use the other two functionst too (if relevant).The "def replace_the_blank(answer, sentence, blank):" function could need some modifying to respond only when the user correctly guess and to use next string accordingly too... I don't know how to go about it.....

Overall, I need help replacing strings that are from the "blank_space" list in the "driver_Knowledge_test" list, and replace it with the "answer_1" list --- all of which should be in ordert too and when the user correctly guesses... Hope that makes sense.

```
driver_knowledge_test = ["When you're going to drive it is important to always put on your ___1___, including your passengers.","If there are no lanes marked on the road, you should drive in the ___2___ side of the road.", "It's getting dark and the sun is fading, you should turn on the ___3___. ","Before driving on a freeway, you should make sure you have enough ___4___, oil, water and the correct tyre pressure."]

answer_1 = ['seatbelts', 'left', 'light', 'fuel']

blank_space = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]
'''goal: collect user's answer and replace sentence with word when answered correct - other loop to rettry'''



def finding_blank(word, pos):
    for ea_blank in word:
        if ea_blank in pos: #This equals to teh whole list.
            return ea_blank
    return None

def replace_the_blank(answer, sentence, blank):
    new_list = []
    blank_index = 0
    answer_index = 0
    sentence_index = 0
    for ea_element in sentence:
        blank_number = finding_blank(sentence[sentence_index], blank)
        if blank_number == blank[blank_index]:
            blank_number.replace(blank_index, answer[answer_index])
            blank_index += 1
            answer_index += 1
            sentence_index += 1




"Inputs answer list and sentence string"
"Outputs new sentence when answered correctly"
def answer_check(answer, sentence, blank_space):
    new_list = []
    index = 0
    sentence_index = 0
    answer_index = 0
    blank_index = 0
    while index < sentence:
        print sentence[sentence_index]
        player_answer = raw_input("\nType your answer for " + blank_space[blank_index] + " \n>>>")
        if player_answer.lower() == answer[answer_index]:
            new_list.append(sentence[sentence_index])
            answer_index += 1
            sentence_index += 1
            index += 1
            blank_index += 1
            #print replace_the_blank(answer, sentence, blank)
            print "CCORRECT! \n"
        else:
            print "Wrong! Try again. :) \n"


answer_check(answer_1, driver_knowledge_test, blank_space)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use string [replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method to replace a part of string with another string.

So instead of

```
print replace_the_blank(answer, sentence, blank)
```

try

```
print sentence[sentence_index].replace(blank_space[blank_index], answer[answer_index])
```